# Can I create a selector with multiple elements using Jquery closest()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, closest

I have a listener for click events from which I need to exclude some elements.

Right now my list is growing, so I'm looking for a better way to "bundle" multiple elements in a selector.

This is what I have:

```
$(document).on('click tap', function(event) {               
    if ($(event.target).closest('div:jqmData(panel="popover")').length > 0 ||
        $(event.target).closest('div.pop_menuBox').length > 0 ||
        $(event.target).closest('.toggle_popover').length > 0 ) ||
        $(event.target).closest('.ui-selectmenu').length > 0 {
          return; 
    }
    // do stuff
});
```

Is there a better way to exclude these elements?

Thanks for help!

Comment: can you update the HTML on which jquery is working?

Comment: Can't you just give each element you want to check the same class?

Comment: not sure what you mean? I'm using Jquery 1.7.1 (and Jquery Mobile)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can specify CSS selectors, which means: you can use the comma to specify two or more selectors:

```
if($(event.target).closest('div:jqmData(panel="popover"), div.pop_menuBox, .toggle_popover, .ui-selectmenu').length > 0) {
    return; 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use a comma.

```
if ($(event.target)
     .closest('div:jqmData(panel="popover"), div.pop_menuBox, .toggle_popover, .ui-selectmenu').length > 0) {
     return; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the jquery documentation you can provide more than one selector for closest: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: yes, I read this too. I was a little unsure what "This signature (only!) is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. This method is primarily meant to be used internally or by plugin authors." on the Jquery page is supposed to mean? What's "signature"?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Does it work for you? I'm also curious as to why jQuery puts it's selectors in an array in the example: ` var close = $("li:first").closest(["ul", "body"]);`

Comment: Ok. Just tried it. If I do a regular selector with comma it works. I assume the array thing is no longer supported. Will test that later on